# Display Datepicker after dynamically loading partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display datepicker after dynamically loading partial view, but the problem is that it is displayed on `Create Page`, but while editing the record it is not seen.

Model :

```
public int CACaseID { get; set; }
public string CompanyName { get; set; }
public string ContractorLicenseNo { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateExpiry { get; set; }
```

Comment: You might want to call the datepicker initialize code again after your refresh the page, if you're using AJAX that is. Not entirely sure after reading your question.

Comment: Yes i want to call the datepicker initialize code again after refreshing a page.